# Loss of data when passing it to Cipher.update while using DES (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, padding, des

Here's the deal:

I have a Buffer of data structured like this:

`[39 bytes of header] + [body] + [padding]` (calculated by me).
If I save it to a file, I can actually recognize the structure, and everything seems fine.

Then, I have to DES-CBC encrypt this buffer, and what I do is

a) Instantiate the DES wrapper, which has a key, and calculates a new IV (autoPadding: false on the Cipher object it creates, too)
b) Pass the buffer to the DES wrapper
c) The buffer then gets encrypted as follows:
(data is the buffer, en is the Cipher object)

```
var buf1 = en.update(data);
```

When I output `buf1` on a file (and then, in my case, on a socket) and retrieve it's bytes, then decrypt it I obtain the following structure:
`[header][body]`
But when I output data on a file and retrieve it's bytes, I get the starting structure.
I know I should also append `en.final()` to `buf1`, but in my case I don't need those values, also with autoPadding being false it would just throw an error.

Comment: **Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: Thank you Artjom, I'm well aware of that, however I need to use DES as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API provides you with a contract. One of the properties of the contract is that you need to call `Cipher#final([output_encoding])` when you finished encrypting. Even if the padding doesn't need to be handled by the `Cipher` instance, the code is written for re-usability and therefore expects to be used in the same way regardless of padding options.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I already thought of it before you posted it and was about to close the question.
The fact is that the final provides my "custom" padding and DES padding too, which I can remove by using slice and obtain what I desire ^^

Thanks!